# Weird error from Visual C++: No default constructor for promise type

Tags: c++, visual-c++, intellisense, c++20, c++-coroutine

Suppose I want to use coroutines with C++20 and restrict the promise type to accept only functions getting one argument of type `int &`. I write the following code:

```cpp
#include <coroutine>

struct task {
  struct promise_type {
    promise_type(int &) {}
    task get_return_object() { return {}; }
    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
    std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    void return_void() {}
    void unhandled_exception() {}
  };
};

task my_task(int &) {
  co_await std::suspend_never{};
}

int main() {
  int x = 5;
  my_task(x);
}
```

This compiles and works fine, both with GCC version 10+ and Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8+.
However, Visual Studio 2019 always complains that no default constructor exists for class "task::promise_type":

[image: no default constructor exists for class "task::promise_type"]

This error does not occur if I do not use a reference (e.g. `int` instead of `int &` as the argument type).
GCC does not show any warning or error, with and without the reference.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is this prohibited by the standard?
Or is it just a weird quirk of IntelliSense?

Comment: If it compiles and works, isn't it just an IntelliSense problem? There's no shortage of those.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that, but I'm just not sure.

Comment: The compiler is the authority on code correctness. IntelliSense will always lag behind, and it is very unlikely to ever be flawless.

Comment: just refresh the intellisense index

Comment: @phuclv That doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a problem of IntelliSense and should work fine. To resolve the intellisense error, a constructor can be added just for IntelliSense:

```
#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__
promise_type();
#endif
```